# Could we rescue, raise and rescue the same error again using exception hierarchy syntax in ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

I would like the exceptions to be rescued, raised and rescued again using exception hierarchy syntax like the below snippet..

```
class InnerCustomError < StandardError
  def initialize(msg = "inner")
    super
  end
end

class OuterCustomError < StandardError
  def initialize(msg = "outer")
    super
  end
end

begin
  raise InnerCustomError
rescue InnerCustomError
  raise OuterCustomError
rescue OuterCustomError, StandardError => e
  e.message
end
```

but this raises ==> `OuterCustomError (outer)`

why is this behaviour? Instead I would like it to be rescued ..

I understand nested begin end blocks like below is used to achieve the same,

```
begin
  begin 
    raise InnerCustomError
  rescue InnerCustomError 
    raise OuterCustomError
  end
rescue OuterCustomError, StandardError => e
  e.message
end
```

also I understand there are performance impacts with this idea but I would like to understand how is the former interpreted?

Comment: Otherwise, you would easily run into infinite loops when (re-) raising exceptions from within `rescue`.

Comment: BTW, what are you trying to achieve? Raising an exception just to rescue it doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: ohh this is a very common pattern.. in my use case I have an API controller that actually handles all JTW InvalidTokenErrors* and re-raise it as a customError, which eventually will be captured again to build a error response with HTTP Status 423 blocking the user and forcing the client to actually log in again..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but this raises `OuterCustomError`. Why is this behaviour?

Because that's how this construct works. The first matching `rescue` is selected as a handler for the exception and the result of this handling will be the result of the `begin/rescue`. If the handler raises and you want to catch that new exception, you need to add another layer of begin/rescue, exactly like you show in the last snippet.

It is described in the documentation [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html#:%7E:text=The%20exception%20is%20matched%20to%20the%20rescue%20section%20starting%20at%20the%20top,%20and%20matches%20only%20once).

Comment: thanks for the explanation.. if possible could you please help me with some references to this behaviour?

Comment: @Sathish see the first example in [Exception Handling](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/doc/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html) – the `# code that might raise` part is between `begin` and `rescue`.

Comment: @sergio-tulentsev I found the actual reference from the docs [here](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/syntax/exceptions_rdoc.html#:~:text=The%20exception%20is%20matched%20to%20the%20rescue%20section%20starting%20at%20the%20top,%20and%20matches%20only%20once)
It explains that the exceptions are matched only once starting from the top..

Comment: @Sathish: ah, thanks! I'll add this to the answer, if you don't mind.